# ADO Recordset Field Value to C++ vector/array (capture pointer value)

Tags: c++, ado, data-conversion

I am trying to query an SQL Server (Express) through Visual C++ (express) and store the resulting dataset into a C++ vector (array would be great as well).  To that end I researched the ADO library and found plenty of help on MSDN.  In short, reference the msado15.dll library and use those features (especially the ADO Record Binding, which requires icrsint.h).  In short, I have been able to query the database and display the field values with printf(); but am stumbling when I try to load the field values into a vector.

I originally tried loading values by casting everything as char* (due to despair after many type conversion errors) only to find the end result was a vector of pointers that all pointed to the same memory address.  Next (and this is the code provided below) I attempted to assign the value of the memory location but am ending up with a vector of the first character of the memory location only.  In short, I need help understanding how to pass the entire value stored by the Recordset Field Value (rs.symbol) pointer (at the time it is passed to the vector) instead of just the first character?  In this circumstance the values returned from SQL are strings.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#import "msado15.dll" no_namespace rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")
#include "iostream"
#include <icrsint.h>
#include <vector>
int j;
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IADORecordBinding, __uuidof(IADORecordBinding));
inline void TESTHR(HRESULT _hr) { if FAILED(_hr) _com_issue_error(_hr); }
class CCustomRs : public CADORecordBinding {
    BEGIN_ADO_BINDING(CCustomRs)
        ADO_VARIABLE_LENGTH_ENTRY2(1, adVarChar, symbol, sizeof(symbol), symbolStatus, false)
        END_ADO_BINDING()
public:
    CHAR symbol[6];
    ULONG symbolStatus;
};
int main() {
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    std::vector<char> tickers;
    try {
        char sym;
        _RecordsetPtr pRs("ADODB.Recordset");
        CCustomRs rs;
        IADORecordBindingPtr picRs(pRs);
        pRs->Open(L"SELECT symbol From Test", L"driver={sql server};SERVER=(local);Database=Securities;Trusted_Connection=Yes;", 
            adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText);
        TESTHR(picRs->BindToRecordset(&rs));
        while (!pRs->EndOfFile) {
            // Process data in the CCustomRs C++ instance variables.
//Try to load field value into a vector
            printf("Name = %s\n",
                (rs.symbolStatus == adFldOK ? rs.symbol: "<Error>"));


//This is likely where my mistake is
sym = *rs.symbol;//only seems to store the first character at the pointer's address


            // Move to the next row of the Recordset.   Fields in the new row will 
            // automatically be placed in the CCustomRs C++ instance variables.
//Try to load field value into a vector
            tickers.push_back (sym); //I can redefine everything as char*, but I end up with an array of a single memory location...
            pRs->MoveNext();
        }
    }
    catch (_com_error &e) {
        printf("Error:\n");
        printf("Code = %08lx\n", e.Error());
        printf("Meaning = %s\n", e.ErrorMessage());
        printf("Source = %s\n", (LPCSTR)e.Source());
        printf("Description = %s\n", (LPCSTR)e.Description());
    }
    ::CoUninitialize();
//This is me running tests to ensure the data passes as expected, which it doesn't
    std::cin.get();
    std::cout << "the vector contains: " << tickers.size() << '\n';
    std::cin.get();
    j = 0;
    while (j < tickers.size()) {
        std::cout << j << ' ' << tickers.size() << ' ' << tickers[j] << '\n';
        j++;
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `std::vector<char*>` does not work because the same buffer is used for all the records. So when `pRs->MoveNext()` is called, the new content is loaded into the buffer, overwriting the previous content.

You need to make a copy of the content.

I would suggest using a `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
std::vector<std::string> tickers;
...

    tickers.push_back(std::string(rs.symbol));
```

Comment: Hey alain (I didn't downvote this, just FYI) - I took your advice and recast the tickers vector and push_back line as you mentioned.  However, when I have the program print the values in the resulting vector using printf("%s\n", tickers[j]);  the values stored in the vector appear to be jibberish...  Am I missing something else here?

Comment: You could either use `cout << ` as in the question, or `printf("%s\n", tickers[j].c_str());`. I know you didn't downvote, I guess it's because of a comment I wrote on meta.

Comment: Gotcha - I will have to research more to understand why we needed to use .c_str() method/property (I can certainly presume).  But let me tell you, I have been struggling with this for a while and you just made my week!

Comment: :-) Thanks. `printf` is a C function, and `string` is a C++ thing. `c_str()` gives you a C-style string.

Answer (score 0):

Why you did not use `std::string` instead of `std::vector`?
To add characters use one of these member functions:
`basic_string& append( const CharT* s );` - for cstrings, 
`basic_string& append( const CharT* s,size_type count );` - otherwise.
Read more at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append.

If you want a line breaks, simply append `'\n'` where you want it.

Comment: Not sure if I understand this one.  I want to use an array because I will have many elements - that array/vector will then be used to create additional arrays/vectors; so I wanted to use a vector to help manage the workflow.  I'm not looking to have one long string here.

Comment: Yes, `string.append` is for appending single characters to a string, so this doesn't work here.